# Can I make my terminal color scheme variable upon my cwd?

Tags: gnome-terminal

Self explanatory, for example when I `cd Desktop` the response is nominal in addition to the term color scheme changing from the palette assigned to `~` to one assigned to `~/Desktop`

Comment: Relevant, but doesn't work with gnome-terminal: [this answer on "How can I change the colors of my xterm using Ansi escape sequences?"](https://superuser.com/a/366817/443564)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to my other answer, but it uses an ANSI escape sequence to toggle reverse video mode on or off for just the current terminal.

Put this in your `~/.bashrc`:

```bash
_terminal_reverse_video_cwd(){
    if [[ $PWD == ~/Desktop ||
          $PWD == ~/Desktop/* ]]
    then
        printf '\e[?5h' # Reverse
    else
        printf '\e[?5l' # Non-reverse
    fi
}

PROMPT_COMMAND="_terminal_reverse_video_cwd"
```

There are two annoyances with reverse video mode:

1. It can only be on or off, so this method only works for one directory
2. It can be ugly/hard to read

Answer (score 2):

You could have the `$PROMPT_COMMAND` change the terminal color settings, but it would change the color scheme in every terminal window, not just the current one.

For 14.04, put the below into your `~/.bashrc`. You may want to backup your current gconf settings before proceeding.

```bash
_terminal_colors(){
    local dir="/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/$TERMINAL_PROFILE"
    
    local bg_default="#30300A0A2424"
    local bg_xterm="#147A147A147A"
    local bg
    
    local fg_default="#FFFFFFFFFFFF"
    local fg_xterm="#EEEEEEEEECEC"
    local fg
    
    local palette_default="#2E2E34343636:#CCCC00000000:#4E4E9A9A0606:#C4C4A0A00000:#34346565A4A4:#757550507B7B:#060698209A9A:#D3D3D7D7CFCF:#555557575353:#EFEF29292929:#8A8AE2E23434:#FCFCE9E94F4F:#72729F9FCFCF:#ADAD7F7FA8A8:#3434E2E2E2E2:#EEEEEEEEECEC"
    local palette_xterm="#000000000000:#CDCB00000000:#0000CDCB0000:#CDCBCDCB0000:#1E1A908FFFFF:#CDCB0000CDCB:#0000CDCBCDCB:#E5E2E5E2E5E2:#4CCC4CCC4CCC:#FFFF00000000:#0000FFFF0000:#FFFFFFFF0000:#46458281B4AE:#FFFF0000FFFF:#0000FFFFFFFF:#FFFFFFFFFFFF"
    local palette
    
    if [[ $PWD == ~/Desktop ||
          $PWD == ~/Desktop/* ]]
    then
        palette="$palette_xterm"
        bg="$bg_xterm"
        fg="$fg_xterm"
    else
        palette="$palette_default"
        bg="$bg_default"
        fg="$fg_default"
    fi
    
    gconftool-2 --set "$dir/palette" --type=string "$palette"
    gconftool-2 --set "$dir/background_color" --type=string "$bg"
    gconftool-2 --set "$dir/foreground_color" --type=string "$fg"
}

TERMINAL_PROFILE="" # Your profile here.
PROMPT_COMMAND="_terminal_colors"
```

For 16.04 and newer, you'll need to adapt the commands to use `dconf` instead of `gconftool-2`. It's a totally different syntax and directory structure.

---

#### Simpler solution

So given the complexity of the above, I think it's easier to just set the color of the pwd in the PS1 prompt. This is forwards and backwards compatible, and probably cross-platform too:

```bash
_PROMPT_pwd_color(){
    if [[ $PWD == ~/Desktop ||
          $PWD == ~/Desktop/* ]]
    then
        printf "\e[1;31m" # Red
    else
        printf "\e[1;32m" # Green
    fi
}

PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[1;32m\]\u@\h\[\e[m\]:\[$(_PROMPT_pwd_color)\]\w\[\e[m\]\n\$ '
```

Comment: Close but as you said "it would change the color scheme in every terminal window, not just the current one." and I'd like to be able differentiate quickly between a number of terminal windows. +1 for the effort none the less!